# How to access process.ENV variable in client side code

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

What I want is to do certain staff on prod/qa/dev environment but by calling my lib. So the lib code, even on client side, need to know certain env variables.

Comment: That is [not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315708/reading-environment-variables-with-javascript)

Comment: So I came across [this](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/272) by which it seems I can do `new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.x': y
        }) ` but then my question is, would it be passed to client side with this value?

Comment: no, those are for webpack and are only used at build time. Not when you run the app. If you want authentication/authorization in the client at run time you need to create an api where users can log in and get authorization for admin stuff.

Comment: Well not auth, I was trying to write some debugging library (putting debug info in page and console) which will only work for non-prod env. To do that, the library needs to know info of what env it is. But I think I got my answer. So I will try to find an alternative way. Thanks.