# How to fetch System Variables in Angular 2 & 4?

Tags: node.js, angular

Is there any way to fetch operating system variables in Angular like Java and Path. same like we have in Node.js "process.env.JAVA".

I have tried googling it but everyone is saying create a file environment.ts but this is not my requirement, i need to fetch the System variable in Angular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading environment variables with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315708/reading-environment-variables-with-javascript)

Comment: So its not possible to fetch OS variable in JavaScript  or is it not recommended ???

Comment: You can during compile time of course, but not during runtime. See this article: https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659

Comment: Just pay attention that Angular is running on browser of the user, so do you wan to access user system variables?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?