# Making download in APPDATA

Tags: windows, vbscript, hta

How can I make this script download the file under %APPDATA% or the script location for saving the file be under %APPDATA%?

```
dim http_obj
dim stream_obj
dim shell_obj

set http_obj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
set stream_obj = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
set shell_obj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

URL = "http://www.mikemurr.com/example.exe"
FILENAME = "example.exe"

http_obj.open "GET", URL, False
http_obj.send

stream_obj.type = 1
stream_obj.open
stream_obj.write http_obj.responseBody
stream_obj.savetofile FILENAME, 2

shell_obj.run FILENAME
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23352251/1169519